# jboss.xml for JBoss EAP 6.3.0

Tags: xml, jboss-eap-6

here is my jboss.xml and I am not sure whether it is correct or not (the tags) for JBoss EAP 6.3.0. The names I have used for jndi-names are in the correct format? Please help me out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS 3.2//EN"
                       "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss_3_2.dtd">                                              
<jboss>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <entity>
            <ejb-name>D</ejb-name>
            <local-jndi-name>java:ejb/D</local-jndi-name>
            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>D</res-ref-name>
                <jndi-name>ejb/D</jndi-name>
            </resource-ref>
        </entity>
        <entity>
            <ejb-name>JVTInventorySession</ejb-name>
            <local-jndi-name>java:ejb/jvtnventorysession</local-jndi-name>
            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jvtnventorysession</res-ref-name>
                <jndi-name>ejb/jvtnventorysession</jndi-name>
            </resource-ref>
        </entity>
        <entity>
            <ejb-name>XVTInventoryMDB</ejb-name>
            <local-jndi-name>java:ejb/xvtinventorymdb</local-jndi-name>
            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>xvtinventorymdb</res-ref-name>
                <jndi-name>ejb/jvtnventorysession</jndi-name>
            </resource-ref>
        </entity>
        <security-domain>SC</security-domain>
       </enterprise-beans>
</jboss>
```

Answer (score 0):

When migrating Entity Beans to JBoss EAP 6 you should put most of the configuration inside `ejb-jar.xml` like this:

```
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID" version="3.2"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_2.xsd">

    <enterprise-beans>
        <entity>
            <ejb-name>D</ejb-name>
            <home>com.a.b.DHome</home>
            <remote>com.a.b.DRemote</remote>
            <ejb-class>com.a.b.DBean</ejb-class>
            <persistence-type>Bean</persistence-type>
            <prim-key-class>com.a.b.DPK</prim-key-class>
            <reentrant>false</reentrant>
        </entity>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

In `jboss.xml` you usually only require the ejb-name and the jndi-name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS 3.2//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss_3_2.dtd">
<jboss>  
  <enterprise-beans>
    <entity>
      <ejb-name>D</ejb-name>
      <jndi-name>ejb/entity/D</jndi-name>
    </entity>   
  </enterprise-beans>  
</jboss>
```

The DTDs themselves have further information about the available elements